# F# project autogenerate bindingRedirect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, .net-assembly, csproj

I'd like to play around in F# with our company internal libraries. They are published to our nuget store.

Problem:
There is Library A, version 1.0.0.0, which depends on library B, version 1.0.0.15. Possibly, there might be dependency from A to C, which in turn depends on B, version 1.0.0.somethingelse, I'm not completely sure.

Now, if I fool around with this in C#, the only thing I do is downloading the A nuget package, and when the compiler warns me that It wants to add assembly binding redirect, I simply allow it, and that's the end of the story, everything works.

The question is, can Visual studio do this if I reference the same nuget packages from a F# project?

And perhaps, is there a way to go about things using VSCode, Ionide and paket?

Answer (score 4):

You can [create binding redirects using `paket`](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Redirects-option) by setting

```
redirects: on
```

in your `paket.dependencies`.
Paket will however only change *existing* `*.config`s, to create new ones, run

```
paket install --createnewbindingfiles
```